# Xamarin.Auth AccountStore - KeyStore was not initialized

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I've had this Xamarin.Auth AccountStore working in my app for a while, but then decided to do some updates to some Nuget Packages and Target Android versions >_<

I now have no idea what went wrong and how to get it working again, here is the exception:

```
Java.Security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore was not initialized
```

The code is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
var accountStore = AccountStore.Create(Android.App.Application.Context);
var accounts = accountStore.FindAccountsForService(providerName);
```

The 2nd line is throwing the exception.
This is in the Android project, being called from a PCL DependencyService.
It has been working this way for a while, I guess something changed in a version update in one of the packages but I don't know what, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to repair your visual studio installation.
This made the trick for our project. We had the same problems like you.